# Add line above and below text

Tags: adobe-photoshop, paragraph-styles

There was a way to do it with InDesign, but I can't find the instructions for Photoshop CC 2017. I tried looking for paragraph rules, but I can't locate it. I'm trying to replicate the date heading on this picture.

[image: picture].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photoshop is not geared toward more advanced typesetting options.

You'll have to *draw* the lines, at least the top one, if you want it.

Comment: How would you do the double lines for underline? And which tool would you suggest to draw the top?

Comment: @user3730393 I would draw both paths with the the pen tool, then merely adjust the stroke options. -- To be completely honest, I'd use Illustrator and place the photo in an .ai file. Or set the type up in .ai and place it as a smart object in Photoshop. That doesn't mean that method is "correct" by any means. But that's how I'd handle it.